# Iterate through a JSON named array of dictionaries with swift 2.1

Tags: ios, json, swift2

I'm pulling a JSON array of dictionaries trying to add them to a class I created and use them for a `UITableView`. The JSON would look like this:

```
   {  
       "inventory":[  
          {  
             "item":"item 1",
             "description":"item 1 description",
             "quantityOnHand":"42",
             "supplier_id":"1",
             "supplierName":"Supplier 1"
          },
          {  
             "item":"item 2",
             "description":"item 2 description",
             "quantityOnHand":"1001",
             "supplier_id":"1",
             "supplierName":"Supplier 1"
          } ...
```

and so on...

I'm grabbing all this in my `viewDidLoad()` and trying to add each dictionary to a class (called `Inventory`) to work with later.  Here's where I'm serializing my JSON:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlString = "my url to json data";
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!;

    session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let responseData = data {
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

                print(json) //this prints out the above formatted json



                 if let dict = json as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        print(dict["inventory"]![0]!["description"]);
                        print(dict["inventory"]![0]!["item"]);
                        print(dict["inventory"]![0]!["quantityOnHand"]);
                 }
            } catch {
                print("Could not serialize");
            }
       }
    }.resume()
}
```

I'm able to print out each value using something like `print(dict["inventory"]![0]!["description"]);` but that seems inefficient.

Do I need a for loop counting the number of dictionaries? Or a `for (key, value)` loop?  The fact that it's a bunch of dictionaries inside of an array named `inventory` is really throwing me off.  If it were JSON returning key:value pairs  in a single dictionary I think I could figure it out on my own.  I'm sort of stuck on what to do after putting my `json["inventory"]` into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all cast the JSON serialization to something meaningful,
in this case `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Then retrieve the array of dictionaries, the JSON string reveals that it contains only `String` types.

```
let inventoryArray = dict["inventory"] as! [Dictionary<String, String>]
```

if `inventory` is optional, use optional bindings

```
if let inventoryArray = dict["inventory"] as? [Dictionary<String, String>] { }
```

Now you can get the items in the array with a simple loop, any type casting is not needed.

```
for anItem in inventoryArray {
   print("description:", anItem["description"])
   print("item: ", anItem["item"])
   print("quantityOnHand: ", anItem["quantityOnHand"])
}
```

Comment: This is very useful, but does my Dictionary HAVE to be String, String for my JSON?  I assumed it was passing the value from the db which is an Int.  i have objects that match the json that require the correct data types, whether it's Int or String.

Comment: If there could by other value types like `Int` you have to cast the array to `[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]` and also the subscripted items to the specific type e.g. `anItem["description"] as! String`. However your sample JSON string does contain only `String` values.

Comment: You're right they are strings. I didn't notice that at first. Strange. I'll have to check my APIs or maybe cast them in swift.  Thank you!!